# interaction with keyboard/textfields help please

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

Normally for a string to object is converted as follows.

```
var obj:object=getChildByName("string");
```

And we can give properties to it like `obj.x=100;`But in the case of a series of stings

```
[objet Stage].[object MainTimeline].[object TextField]
```

it wil not works.Actually i need to give properties to a target path which is a string
what i do??
*Here is the code to get path to a movieclip:*

```
 addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, targetMC);
function targetMC(MouseEvent:Event):void
{
 var curinstance = MouseEvent.target.valueOf();
 var targ:Object = curinstance.parent;
 var path = curinstance;
 do
 {
  if (targ == "[object Stage]")
  {
   path = targ + "." + path;
  }
  else
  {

   path = targ + "." + path;
  }

  targ = targ.parent;
 } while (targ);


 trace(path);

}
```

**i would like to give properties to path**.

Comment: Hi dude, I am not sure what you really try to do. What is the main purpose?

Comment: actually am dealing with keybord interaction.In this when a key is pressed on any of the textfields.I would like to pass the char code to tat object..

Comment: Please either edit the question or post comments to add additional information or ask other users to clarify their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of things are awkward about your code:

1. Don't compare the string value of objects to find out about class type.  Use the `is` keyword:

   ```
   if (obj.parent is Stage) doSomething();
   ```
2. Don't use class names as parameter names:  MouseEvent is a type!

   ```
   function targetMC ( ev:MouseEvent ) // ...more code
   ```
3. It is useful to name handler methods according to the event upon which they are invoked, for example:

   ```
   function onMouseClick (ev:MouseEvent)
   ```

   or

   ```
   function mouseClickHandler (ev:MouseEvent)
   ```
4. If you can avoid it, don't cast to `Object` to access members, but try to use subclass types - it allows the compiler to more effectively check your code for errors. Since all objects in the display list are instances of `DisplayObject`, you could use this:

   ```
   var obj:DisplayObject = ev.target as DisplayObject;
   ```
5. If you want to output a path to your object, use instance names instead of types - you might have more than one TextField!

   ```
   private function getObjectPath (obj:DisplayObject) : String {
       var path:String = obj.name;
       if (obj.parent != null && !(obj.parent is Stage)) {
           path = getObjectPath (obj.parent) + "." + path;
       }
       return path;
   }
   ```

Now for your answer:  Use the KeyboardEvent.

```
textField.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
```

and

```
private function onKeyUp (ev:KeyboardEvent) : void {
    var tf:TextField = ev.target as TextField;
    var text:String = tf.text;
    tf.text = text + String.fromCharCode(charCode);
}
```

Note that this will only work as long as the TextField has focus, that is the user has to click it first.

Comment: @weltraumpirat in the above function getobjectpath() there get some output.which is in terms of string. How do i convert those to route to a particular object?

Comment: here in tf.text i got the string but my problem is that to convert/pass these value to a focused text area/textfied

Comment: Heloo guys. from above codes i get like this[object Stage].[objec Maintimeline].[object moieclip]..i Have to give properties to that object like texbioox

Comment: You don't need a full path for that.  A reference to the TextField is passed to the handler function in the event parameter.  Look at the onKeyUp method above - just use `ev.target as TextField;`

Comment: And still: Please read the ActionScript documentation.  You won't get far unless you start reading stuff.

Comment: from your code i get targetpath of the moiveclip/txtfield in terms of string..i have to give properties to that only...what i do?

Comment: I need when i focused in a particular textfield i have to append text from the keyboard.so in the keyboard movieclip i have to give variable which encloses  the path.

Comment: my task is. doing with keyboard interaction..In that i made 2 movieclips.one for the keyboard and other for the forms which contain s the textfields.Whenever i focused on a particular textfield the keyboard appears from the libraryusing (addchild())method.i have to pass the key pressed text to the form hhaving the textfields..

Comment: Akhil, we have been very patient.  You need to start using this site the way it is intended: **Edit your question, if you want to add more information.**  Spamming the page with comments will confuse others.

Comment: @Akhil: Read at least half of the links on this page: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8cf79-8000.html  Then, if you have more questions, come back and post another one.  You will not be able to get anywhere without knowing the basics of programming with ActionScript, and I don't have enough spare time to teach you. I assure you, this advice is meant well - trust me, you will understand much more of the answers you have already been given.

Comment: @Akhil: I can, but I won't do your work for you.  You have been given all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass a key charCode to a TextField, the latter should listen to a KeyboardEvent and retrieve the info from the event's charCode property
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

Your perspective of AS3 is "different"... For instance getChildByName doesn't convert a String to an Object, it basically does what the method name states , it retrieves a parent's child using its name as a reference.

It looks like you're adapting whatever language you're coming from to AS3. I doubt this will work...

Comment: @patrik s i just done that for getting the object..ya i know what it means.did u know any alternatives to convert a string to object?.

Comment: import flash.events.Event;
var str:String = "Object(root).mc_clip";
var path:Object = str;
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickmouse);
function clickmouse(ev:Event):void
{
 path.gotoAndStop("2");
}